# Why it gives an error after click on place order button on check out page?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, payment-gateway

This is my code at checkout page. I was developed custom payment gateway plugin for it, but when i am try to click on place order button it is not submitting the request parameters and not getting response ?

public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
        global $woocommerce;

```
    // Get this Order's information so that we know
    // who to charge and how much
    $customer_order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // Are we testing right now or is it a real transaction
    $Mode = ( $this->Mode == "yes" ) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';

    // Decide which URL to post to
    $environment_url = ( "FALSE" == $Mode ) 
                       ? 'https://www.qpayindia.com/wwws/Payment/PaymentDetails.aspx'
                       : 'https://www.qpayindia.com/wwws/Payment/PaymentDetails.aspx';

    // This is where the fun stuff begins
    $payload = array(
        // Authorize.net Credentials and API Info
        "QPayID"                => $this->QPayID,
        "QPayPWD"               => $this->QPayPWD,
        "CaseNumber"            => $this->CaseNumber,

        "Mode"                  => $this->Mode,
        "Currency"              => $this->Currency,
        "Amount"                => $customer_order->order_total,

        "ResponseURL"           => $customer_order->get_checkout_payment_url(),
        "OrderID"               => str_replace( "#", "", $customer_order->get_order_number() ),


        // Some Customer Information
        "x_cust_id"             => $customer_order->user_id,
        "x_customer_ip"         => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],*/

    );

    // Send this payload to Authorize.net for processing
    $response = wp_remote_post( $environment_url, array(
        'method'    => 'POST',
        'body'      => http_build_query( $payload ),
        'timeout'   => 90,
        'sslverify' => false,
    ) );

    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) 
        throw new Exception( __( 'We are currently experiencing problems trying to connect to this payment gateway. Sorry for the inconvenience.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ) );

    if ( empty( $response['body'] ) )
        throw new Exception( __( 'Authorize.net\'s Response was empty.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ) );

    // Retrieve the body's resopnse if no errors found
    $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

    // Parse the response into something we can read
    foreach ( preg_split( "/\r?\n/", $response_body ) as $line ) {
        $resp = explode( "|", $line );
    }

    // Get the values we need
    $r['ResponseCode']             = $resp[0];
    $r['response_sub_code']         = $resp[1];
    $r['response_reason_code']      = $resp[2];
    $r['Message']      = $resp[3];

    // Test the code to know if the transaction went through or not.
    // 1 or 4 means the transaction was a success
    if ( ( $r['ResponseCode'] == 100 ) || ( $r['ResponseCode'] == 200 ) ) {
        // Payment has been successful
        $customer_order->add_order_note( __( 'Qpay payment completed.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ) );

        // Mark order as Paid
        $customer_order->payment_complete();

        // Empty the cart (Very important step)
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

        // Redirect to thank you page
        return array(
            'result'   => 'success',
            'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $customer_order ),
        );
    } else {
        // Transaction was not succesful
        // Add notice to the cart
        wc_add_notice( $r['Message'], 'error' );
        // Add note to the order for your reference
        $customer_order->add_order_note( 'Error: '. $r['Message'] );
    }

}
```

Comment: We are currently experiencing problems trying to connect to this payment gateway. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: For debugging, change your `throw Exception` line to `echo $response->get_error_message();` to show the actual error being thrown by `wp_remote_post()`

Comment: now it will open blank error field on same page..

Comment: [link](http://gold.dinpl.com/wordpress/index.php/checkout/)